# How to debug a stack overflow in C in IAR Workbench

Tags: c, debugging, memory-leaks, stack-overflow, iar

I'm working on a C project using IAR Embedded Workbench IDE and the TI CC2540 Bluetooth Low Energy 8051 chip.

I seem to be getting tons of XData stack and Idata stack overflows while working on the project, and it has been very difficult for me to determine where the overflows are coming from.  I am working with a significant amount of strings via the UART ports.

I was wondering if anyone had any tips on how to ensure that I am deallocating memory after I've allocated, and ensure that I stay within the boundaries of my stack and heap.

Thanks

Comment: Know your stack size, check the code to see if you're using any non-static large arrays or structs in your function, which is likely to cause stack overflow.

Comment: Are you using the stack view to monitor your stack usage? It will tell you which items are on your stack, and how full it is.

Comment: so right now, I have a large struct that I dynamically alloc and dealloc as necessary and passing as a pointer. I never really have more than one of these structs created at a time.  The struct also contains a pointer to a string which I also alloc and dealloc.  Is there a difference between statically creating this struct or not?  I can't see how you can have a static declaration of this struct and also pass it by reference.

Answer (score 4):

Well, in order to avoid stack overflow you should avoid the following things:

1)Recursion (it's not a good idea to use recursion in embedded systems)

2)Try to avoid dynamic allocation. In most cases you do not need it.

In automotive, there are several rules for programming ECUs called the MISRA rules which advise against the use of dynamically allocated memory and recursion. Here's a [link](http://www.ristancase.com/html/dac/manual/3.12.02%20MISRA-C%202004%20Rules.html)

IAR Embedded Workbench is one of the few IDEs that have supports MISRA C. Try to enable the MISRA C option (this may indicate where your problems lay). See how it's done [here](http://www.iar.com/en/Products/IAR-Embedded-Workbench/Technology/MISRA-C/).

Comment: I agree with you about dynamic allocation. I removed all instances where arrays were allocated dynamically and the problems seem to have minimized a bit

Comment: You can also try to modify the stack segment size from your linker. Search your linker file and modify the length of STACK_SEGMENT (from what I recall). This way, you will probably have no more stack overflow problems.

Answer (score 4):

From [this TI's forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/f/538/t/229990), just trying to shed some light over TI's 2540/1 stack size.

When you have compiled your project you can have a look at the bottom in the ".map" file (Output Folder).

For example, the heart rate example project:

```
108 019 bytes of CODE memory
     26 bytes of DATA memory (+ 73 absolute )
  6 089 bytes of XDATA memory
    192 bytes of IDATA memory
      8 bits of BIT memory
    702 bytes of CONST memory
```

This information is useful, in that it tells the total amount of code space (CODE memory) and RAM (XDATA memory) being used by the project. The sum of the CODE memory plus CONST memory must not exceed the maximum flash size of the device (either 128KB or 256KB, depending on the version of the CC2540/41). The size of the XDATA memory must not exceed 7936 bytes, as the CC2540/41 contains 8kB of SRAM (256 bytes are reserved).

While keeping a keen watch on your XDATA not to exceed ~8k, you may want to adjust the buffers / big arrays defined your code. The minimal SimpleBLEPeripheral app itself consumes close to 6-7k memory, on top of which there is just enough room to allocate some memory for your app resources.

[I know, very late answer, but may help other readers].

Answer (score 0):

You can change the stack and heap sizes in your linker configuration (.icf) file. Project-> Options-> Linker-> Config. Minor changes can be made built-in editor but it is so pathetic that you should just use a text editor.

There you'll see something like:

```
define block CSTACK with alignment = 8, size = 0x0400 {};
define block HEAP with alignment = 8, size = 0x0200 {};
place in MY_RAM_region {block CSTACK, block HEAP};
```

and you can change as appropriate. I think it is ok to set HEAP size to zero. Then all malloc calls will fail at runtime, but the cool kids don't use dynamic memory in embedded systems anyway.

How to estimate the stack size? The EWB manual suggests adding this to your .icf:

```
check that size(block CSTACK) >= 
      maxstack("Program Entry") + totalstack("interrupt") + 100;
```

This is suppose to throw an error if CSTACK is too small (100 is just a fudge factor.) In my case the linker just threw the error "I can't figure out your stack size".

IAR's .icf format reminds me of AppleScript (not in a good way).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if for non-arm edition of IAR this works fine, I can share our approach:

In the startup file we just edit the initialization of the RAM with a pattern that is used by IAR to measure stack usage:

```
    LDR R1, =__RAM_START
    LDR R2, =__RAM_END

    SUBS    R2, R2, R1
    SUBS    R2, #1
    BLE .LC5

    MOVS    R0, #0xCDCDCDCD ;; <- LOOK HERE!
    MOVS    R3, #4
.LC4:
    STR R0, [R1]
    ADD R1, R1, R3
    SUBS R2, #4
    BGE .LC4
```

Then in the options for my node, in linker->advanced we mark Enable stack usage analysis.
In the IDE options we select "enable graphical stack" etc etc.

Now, in debug session we enable the graphic representation of the stack selecting View-> Stack.

With this approach you can also dump your entire RAM and spot where and if 0xCDCD pattern is left.

Another approach involves the DWT OR the MPU in our uC to watch for bus access  crossing boundaries and trigger an exception. With this approach you can see exactly who was doing what when the stack overflowed.

Again, this is an ARM-tailored approach that I don't know if this can work in your system.

K.R.